# dd() not working in vue-laravel project axios call.Is it possible to use dump in axios call?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using vue with laravel.but my save function not working. So I tried to dump and die the request object but I can't see the request object in the preview. it is blank.

```php
protected function save()
{
    $request = Request::all();
    dd($request);
    $suggestion = new Suggestion();
    $suggestion->connection_id = $request['connection_id'];
    $suggestion->company_id = $request['company_id'];
    $suggestion->module = $request['module'];
    $suggestion->description = $request['image'];
    $suggestion->save();
    return 'success';
}
```

the axios call is

```js
axios.post('suggestion/save', this.post).then(response => {
    this.$swal({
        title: 'Success',
        text: response.data.message,
        type: 'success',
        confirmButtonText: 'OK',
    });
    this.$router.push('/suggestion-list');
})
```

Comment: what is inside `this.post`?

Comment: why are you using this.post as a second param in the axios.post()?

Comment: this.post will be like       post: {
          connection_id: 2,
          company_id: 2,
          module: 'customer',
          title: 'title',
          description: 'ewewewewew bggg',
        }, an object whose values taken from a form

Comment: this.post  is to pass values to the controller

Comment: try to get particular data from `this.post` by using                           `$connection_id= $request->input('connection_id');`

Comment: Between how you defined the controller name ?  `public function ControllerName(Request $request) {` ? . Like this ?

Comment: I found the problem.sorry it was with my web route and request facade I used.thanks for the help and support..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add request to your function

also add 'use Illuminate\Http\Request'

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request

public function myFunction(Request $request)

{
    dd($request->all()); 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple Request classes in Laravel, One thing you can try is the following,

```
public function controllerFunction()

{
  dd(request()->all()); 
  $suggestion = new Suggestion();
  $suggestion->connection_id = $request['connection_id'];
  $suggestion->company_id = $request['company_id'];
  $suggestion->module = $request['module'];
  $suggestion->description = $request['description'];
  $suggestion->save();
  return 'success';   
}
```

So irrespective of your class, the `request()` function will bring up the appropriate object.

If you get to dump the request then you can confirm that the request is hitting the appropriate controller function, otherwise, the request is going somewhere else. check the network tab in chrome for more details.

Also, make sure you have the appropriate `Request` class in the `use` statements.

The correct `Request` class usage is like following

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you can use `print()` or `print_r()` to check result

and make sure your this.post has data or not

Comment: still response is blank :(

Comment: kindly check if you are sending data in this.post

Comment: I found the problem it was with my request Facade. thanks for the support:)